# Regex for passport

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to implement regex validation for passport number.

1. Length: 5-20 char Alphanumeric
2. Allowed characters: a-z, A-Z, 0-9 (case insensitive)
3. Cannot contain only 1 digit or character, repeated

**Example: (what I expect to see)**

Z1234aZ - false // "Z" is repeated

aVBNa1 - false // "a" is repeated

ZXCVB123 - true

12zv - false // length 4

My regex: **/^(.){2,}[A-Za-z0-9]{5,20}$/** but it doesn't work

How can i match that none of symbols doesn't repeat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm thinking maybe you can use:

```
^(?:([A-Z\d])(?!.*\1)){5,20}$
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/38WNX0/1). Using case-insensitive matching it would mean:

- `^` - Start line anchor.
- `(?:` - Open non-capture group:

  - `([A-Z\d])` - Capture single character from class.
  - `(?!.*\1)` - Negative lookahead to prevent matched character to occur again using a backreference to 1st capture group.
  - `){5,20}` - Close non-capture group and match 5-20 times.
- `$` - End line anchor.

---

Not sure if I read it correctly, but if you require at least two digits and at least to alpha-chars then maybe add two positive lookaheads:

```
^(?=.*\d.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z].*[A-Z])(?:([A-Z\d])(?!.*\1)){5,20}$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

^(?!^0+$)[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,20}$

Or

^[A-PR-WYa-pr-wy][1-9]\d\s?\d{4}[1-9]$